# Import wikipedia from sift.corpora

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sift

I'm new to spark and cannot import wikipedia package from sift.corpora.
I'm getting this error. " ImportError: No module named 'sift.corpora ".  Here is the notebook I'm working on. Thank you for your help!

https://github.com/wikilinks/sift/blob/master/sift.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance this is a python issue and not a spark issue. The error message is telling you that it cannot find the module you want to import. The sift [documentation](https://github.com/wikilinks/sift) tells you that you have to install the python package before you can use it with:

```
pip install git+http://git@github.com/wikilinks/sift.git
```

You have to execute this command on every spark node as spark is a distributed environment.